# Is there a way to change the self variables from a class init in another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Pretty much what I want to do is permanently alter the variable of one class from a function in another class, is this something that's possible? Or will I have to create a new function to specifically deal with it?

To explain (in a very skeletal example of how my code is set up currently):

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number # for this example the number is 5 to begin with
        self.dictionary = {(1, 0): 'a', (2,0): 'b'}
    # ...some other code for the class

class B(): # note that B DOES NOT inherit from A
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._number = number
        self._A = A(self._number)

    def do_stuff(self) -> None: # it is a requirement to not return anything
        number = self._A.number
        dictionary = self._A.dictionary
        # Printing them now would just give 5 and {(1, 0): 'a', (2,0): 'b'}
        # what I want to do is something like this:

        self._A.number = self._A.number + 5 
# so that ANY time I use self.number from A() it will be 10
```

Is this something that's possible to do or not really? I read a bit about public vs private variables (thus why in A they don't have an underscore but in B they do) and it said that they can be changed and used outside their class but it doesn't seem to work.

It only works in THAT function, THAT time, the one that made the changes that is, and not in subsequent functions or even if I call the same function again.

Like if I were to call them again later to print them from another function in B it prints `5` and `{(1, 0): 'a', (2,0): 'b'}` and not `10` and `{(6, 0): 'a', (7,0): 'b'}`  as I want it to.

For anyone who wants more info on what exactly I'm doing, I'm trying to make a 2 dimensional game set up on a grid, where one class (the equivalent of A()) deals solely with the positioning of entities in the grid as a dictionary mapping a tuple to a character representation. The other class (the equivalent of B()) deals with the actual running of the game. The specific function I'm trying to do this for is supposed to change the position of the entities within the grid either left or right by one position, and also moving it to the other side of the screen if it goes out of bounds so that when I later change the display of the game to match the positions everything will be either one place to the left or right.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Calling `do_stuff()` on the same instance of `B` raises the value of `_A.number` by 5 every time. Are you perhaps creating a new instance of `B` in every test you run?

Comment: Really? Maybe I am creating a new instance then, or I'm just dumb, I was going this at like 3am last night so that's entirely possible. Thanks man. Edit: just figured out what I was doing, I was in fact creating a new instance every time when I was testing it, my bad. In that case it should work fine, I think, I don't think I have to create a new instance of b at any point. Again, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible how you had it. I test with the above code you had:

```py
b = B(5)
assert b._A.number == 5
b.do_stuff()
assert b._A.number == 10
```

It appears to work as expected. For a minor simplification, I'd also recommend changing this:

```
self._A.number = self._A.number + 5
```

to this:

```
self._A.number += 5
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, turns out my sleep deprived brain was just creating a second instance of b when I was testing it (was working on this at 3am, bad idea to do that). Thanks for the help man

Comment: haha, no problem. yeah, I wouldn't recommend coding too late into the night :-)